# What would be a good way to handle custom log messages for different files for the same statement in Java?

Tags: java, logging, coding-style

Not sure if this question is posted on the right forum.

Please point me to the right forum if design-type questions are supposed to posted somewhere else.

**Background:**
Java project. Using log4j.xml. Maven. TestNG.

Each test prints statements to two log files - Unfiltered Log file and Filtered Log File.
All the messages are supposed to be printed exactly as they are, in both the files. Except for a few messages, where a modified message (variable values removed) needs to be printed to the second log file (filtered log file).

**Sample Test Code with print statements:**

```
1. printInfo("Login completed");
2. printInfo("Home page displayed");
// Here the value of accountNumber variable is random and changes with each run.
3. printInfo("Account number " + accountNumber + " created", "printUnfilteredMessageOnlyForUnfilteredLog");
4. printInfo("Account number created", "replaceMessageForFilteredLog");
```

The idea is that both the log files would contain Line 1 and Line 2.
Line 3 would go to only to Unfiltered Log File. Line 4 would go only to Filtered Log File.

**Method code:**

```
Logger unfilteredLogFile = Logger.getLogger("unfilteredLogFileLogger");
Logger filteredLogFile = Logger.getLogger("filteredLogFileLogger");

public void printInfo(String message, String level) {
    if (level.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            //Print the same message in both the log files
            unfilteredLogFile.info("Unfiltered Log :"+message);
            filteredLogFile.debug("Filtered Log :"+message);
        } else if (level.equalsIgnoreCase("printUnfilteredMessageOnlyForUnfilteredLog")) {
            unfilteredLogFile.info("Unfiltered Log :"+message);
        } else if (level.equalsIgnoreCase("replaceMessageForFilteredLog")) {
            filteredLogFile.debug("Filtered Log :"+message);
        }
    }
```

This code works successfully as per my requirement.

**CORRECT OUTPUT:**

```
unfilteredLogFile.log:

Unfiltered Log :Login completed
Unfiltered Log :Home page displayed
Unfiltered Log :Account number 4876 created


filteredLogFile.log:

Filtered Log :Login completed
Filtered Log :Home page displayed
Filtered Log :Account number created
```

**Log4j.xml:**

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
                     debug="false">
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param  name="File" value="./log/unfilteredLogFile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="unfilteredLog" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./log/filteredLogFile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    </appender>


    <logger name="unfilteredLogFileLogger" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="filteredLogFileLogger" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="filteredLog"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="filteredLog"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This code works successfully as per my requirement.
However, this means that for every printInfo statement in the code where the replacement needs to be happen, I need to write two lines of code, one for each log file, which doesn't sound like the most optimal way or clean code.

Is there a different design to handle this scenario, but achieve the same output? Or is this the best one possible for this requirement?

I have thought of having a text file which could be a key value pair list.
Key would be the unfiltered message and value would be filtered message. But, couldn't achieve this as the list would not be able to have the random values in it to be compared against.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) has a `replace` parameter that lets you specify a regular expression and a replacement. If you can tolerate a bit of noise in your unfiltered log, you could put some marker before and after the value you want to redact. Then in your filtered log, you could define a replacement rule that matches the markers and replaces with empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, create 3 custom log-levels - UNFILTERED, FILTERED and COMMON - as demonstrated [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#:%7E:text=To%20define%20a%20custom%20log,level%20by%20calling%20the%20Logger). Then make the log-level COMMON a descendant logger (check [here](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-log-messages-to-different-log-files/) and [here](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/)) of both UNFILTERED and FILTERED log-levels so that any thing that is logged to COMMON goes to both of them. This should solve what you want to achieve.

However, this may be a misuse of log levels. It will remove the flexibility of using predefined log-levels - info, debug, error etc.